# getJSON display value in $.each loop

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having trouble getting the right value, in a jQuery $.each loop.

```
        function suggestit() {
            var value = $input.val();

            $.getJSON( "ajax.php?search=" + value + "?suggested_size=5&mode=game", function( data ) {
                $.each(result, function(i, field){
                    $("#results").append("<p>" + field + "</p>");
                });
            });
        }
```

The `suggestit()` function is called when a user stops typing in the `$input` text field.

It should then display all the games from the JSON file.

The JSON looks like this:

```
["data"]=>
    ["attributes"]=>
        // snip
    ["included"]=>
        [0]=>
                ["name"]=>
            string(31) "Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas®"
        [1]=>
                ["name"]=>
            string(31) "Grand Theft Auto V"
```

I want to display the `name` value from the JSON in the $.each `field`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array of games is in the `included` property, but you're not looping through that. And the name of the game is in the `name` property.

```
$.each(result.included, function(i, el) {
    $("#results").append("<p>" + el.name + "</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must always indicate the index of the element to return. try to debug the index to see the correct order of the array

```
function suggestit() {
        var value = $input.val();

        $.getJSON( "ajax.php?search=" + value + "?suggested_size=5&mode=game", function( data ) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                /** for example */
                $("#results").append("<p>" + field.included[i].name + "</p>");
            });
        });
    }
```